# Localphone PBX Trunk, One way audio only

Tags: asterisk

At the moment I can call landline numbers okay on Localphone using my FreePBX trunk, 
but when I call mobiles, they can hear me, but I can't hear them. any suggestions?

PEER Details:

```
type=friend
insecure=very
nat=yes
canreinvite=no
authuser=xxxxxx
username=xxxxxx
fromuser=xxxxxx
fromdomain=localphone.com
secret=xxxxxxxx
host=localphone.com
dtmfmode=rfc2833
```

USER Details

```
disallow=all
allow=GSM&ULAW&PCMA&PCMU
```

Answer (score 0):

You have check your asterisk know external ip and nat/firewall setup correctly

[sip nat](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions)